# damaged file during upload with file_put_contents

Tags: php

I try to upload an image in a directory using file_put_contents,The file is uploaded but it is damaged and I can not open it. here is my code :

```
define('UploadDir','../Dir/images');
$path = "image.png";
$data="..."; //image base64 string
$file = UploadDir ."/". $path;
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
echo $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
```

Comment: damaged how? How large is it? What does `$data` contain? This needs more detail to be workable.

Comment: 'damaged' in what way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> $data="..."; //image base64 string

Assuming `$data` contains what the comment says, if you put a base64 string in an image it will obviously not be a valid image - it will be a file containing a base64 encoded string.

To be valid (or have a chance at being valid) decode the string before writing it to the file:

```
$data="..."; //image base64 string
$file = UploadDir ."/". $path;
$success = file_put_contents($file, base64_decode($data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the directory `../Dir/images chmoded to 777`? sometimes php won't allow you to access directories if they don't have enough permission.
Try to see if it has enough permissions, if not, then set it to `777` and try it.